# django-rest-framework: how to allow http PUT to succeed

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a startup django-rest-framework app, which I'm using to serve data to another Django app
I have no issues with GET, POST, and DELETE, but when I issue a PUT - I get 405
What can I do to fix that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django REST Framework - 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED using SimpleRouter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151860/django-rest-framework-405-method-not-allowed-using-simplerouter)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question: in my case I have this view: class WorkloadDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView): , and I also have this route:  url(r'^workloads/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.WorkloadDetail.as_view()),  POST and DELETE do not have any issues, just PUT.   Can anyone guess as to WHY?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe '405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED' error message caused by request without '/' at the end of the url.

- **Not working** 127.0.0.1:8000/article/9
- **Working** 127.0.0.1:8000/article/9/

---

If not, check how you request it. It's similar to request DELETE method.
This is an example I've just testing using PAW http client application

[PUT Method request screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gTZa.png)

[PUT Method request result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKLEI.png)

Answer (score 0):

if I'm remembering well, I has the same issue. Following the tutorial of django-rest-framework I noticed that pressing PUT botton request and monitoring network tab of chrome developer tools it did a **POST** request instead of **PUT** request.