# Django/drf - delete method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I want to delete likes from my `Likes` table. for which I am making an axios call from the front end with 
`axios({
        method: "delete",
        url:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/delete/`,
        params: { companyid: xyz }
      })`

It is supposed to delete a like that has `company_id = xyz` in it.

The Url looks like this
`path('delete/', DeleteLikesView.as_view()),`
(`/api/` is included in the project's urls.py. So taken care of...)

and the `DeleteLikesView` -

```
class DeleteLikesView(DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Likes.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LikesSerializer


    def perform_destroy(self, request):
        print(self.kwargs['companyid'])
        companyid = self.kwargs['companyid']
        instance = Likes.objects.get(
            company_id=companyid, user_id=request.user.id)
        instance.delete()
```

I am either being stuck with errors `403` (csrf_token error. Although I tried using csrf_exempt, no luck) or `405` method not allowed(for which I refered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17151860/django-rest-framework-405-method-not-allowed-using-simplerouter). the solution in this question puts me back with `403` error)

Any help is appreciated. Thank!

Comment: You have not provided authentication header in request.

Comment: Do I need to provide csrf token or something like that there?

Comment: Well, it depends upon authentication mechanism you are using e.g. Basic Auth, Oauth etc.

Comment: Post urls.py, both for the app and the project urls, post the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Set xsrfHeaderName in request as below:

```
// ...
xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFToken",
// ...
```

Add CSRF_COOKIE_NAME in settings.py

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use token authentication,instead of basicauth, if you use token auth, then csrf error will not come.
You have written

```
instance = Likes.objects.get(company_id=companyid, user_id=request.user.id)
```

in above code, user_id = request.user.id will not work cause you are not logged in the session.You are using api ,u need to provide a token to tell which user is accessing the api.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use decorating the class. 
To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the **dispatch()** method of the class.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class DeleteLikesView(DestroyAPIView):
    ...

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def perform_destroy(self, request):
        ...
```

See more info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class